# I am trying to run this code this error is occuring

Tags: python, pandas

python version 2.7.12

```
import pandas as pd  
df = pd.read_csv("/home/vipul/example.csv", sep=',')  
v = df.pop('address').str.split('\s*\+.*?-\s*', expand=True)  
v.columns = ['city', 'position', 'country']  
df = pd.concat([df, v], 1)  
df.to_csv("/home/vipul/new.csv")`
```

**The error is**

`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'str'`

Comment: Weird error, cannot simulate.

Comment: @jezrael should i use python3 for this ?

Comment: Sure, it should working in python2 & 3 very nice.

Comment: what is the error here ?